# How IntStream avoid hidden boxing costs

Tags: java, performance, lambda

When you have

```
Stream.of(1 ,10).reduce(0,(v1, v2) -> v1 + v2);
```

versus

```
IntStream.of(1 ,10).reduce(0,(v1, v2) -> v1 + v2);
```

How does `IntStream? avoid the hidden boxing costs?

And why is boxing expensive in terms of performance?

Comment: The expanded representation with parameter types for the above would be `Stream.of(1, 10).reduce(0, (Integer v1, Integer v2) -> v1 + v2);` and `IntStream.of(1, 10).reduce(0, (int v1, int v2) -> v1 + v2);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IntStream` is a specialization of `Stream<T>` which process `int primitive` values.

Look at `IntStream` interface:

```
IntStream filter(IntPredicate predicate);
IntStream map(IntUnaryOperator mapper);
...
```

You can see that this interface use only `int primitive` specialized version of `Predicate`, `Function`, `Consumer`... so it does not require boxing to work with int (because it operates directly with int)

About the performance cost of autoboxing, you can refer to [java guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/autoboxing.html):

> It is not appropriate to use autoboxing and unboxing for scientific computing, or other performance-sensitive numerical code

It's because, every time you invoke an operation requires both `int` or `Integer` or put `int` to an `Integer` container, the compiler inject a box/unbox method call for you.

The performance is rather insignificant for normal operations but if you have an intensive loops or time critical lines of code then you should avoid autoboxing.

Answer (score 1):

More of an addendum towards the consequences of boxing: it is not only the direct penalty for various additional method calls.

Keep in mind that the boxing part leads to the creation of **new** objects. Sure, as creating objects is a frequent operation in OOP, that operation is highly optimized. But still: it takes time fetch memory for a new object, and its constructor and all other init steps need to run. That basically adds up. And worse: when you do that on high scale, you put up a significant burden on the garbage collector.

( I remember seeing a question here long time ago where the OP asked why his application was showing extremely high GC activity. Turned out that he was doing some large loop where he boxed int values to Integer objects, just to throw away said objects moments later. Just avoiding that boxing dramatically improved the overall performance characteristics of his application )